# Compare & Remove a specific character from two strings at a time and display the remaining strings

Tags: java, string, variables, logic

my probem is i have two strings like durgaprasad and spandana . here i want to compare 1st string first cahr to the second string all characters if the first sting first char is matched then remove that character from first & second string also, and then display the string (all chars except removed char).
`like`
`durgaprasad`
`spandana`

1st string 1st char - `d`
compare to all chars in 2nd string-
      founded---at position[4]--`d`
remove that char from 1st string & 2nd string
so we get-----
1st string :`urgaprasad`
2nd string :`spanana`

finally i want to get --
1st string--`urgrd`
2nd string--`nn`

i have tried a lot but i have getting compare to above my code is like this

```
      for(int i = 0; i < firstStr.length(); i++) {       
            System.out.println("char position  :"+firstStr.charAt(i));  
            int k = 0;  
            for( int j = 0; j < secondStr.length(); j++) {  
                //System.out.println("second position :"+secondStr.charAt(j));  
                if ( ( firstStr.charAt(i) == secondStr.charAt(j) ) && ( k == 0 ) ) {  
                    secondStr = secondStr.substring( 0 , j ).concat(secondStr.substring( j + 1 ) );<br />firstStr = firstStr.substring( 0 , i ).concat(firstStr.substring( i + 1 ) );  
                }                                          
            }
        }
```

for my requirement what changes i have done here

`Thanks`

Answer (score 1):

Something like...this?

```
public void RemoveCharacter(String s1, String s2) {
    System.out.println("First string: " + s1 + "\nSecond string: " + s2);
    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < s2.length(); j++) {
            if (s1.charAt(i) == s2.charAt(j)) {
                RemoveCharacter(s1.substring(0, i) + s1.substring(i + 1), s2.substring(0, j) + s2.substring(j + 1);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It pretty much has to be a recursive function if you want to continually strip characters, because removing characters screws up the for-loop iterations (although I suppose you *could* do `i--` and `j--` inside the if-statement).

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code.

```
for(int i = 0; i < firstStr.length(); i++) {
    System.out.println("char position :" + firstStr.charAt(i));
    for(int j = 0; j < secondStr.length(); j++) {
        //System.out.println("second position :" + secondStr.charAt(j));
        if (firstStr.charAt(i) == secondStr.charAt(j)) {
            firstStr = firstStr.substring(0, i) + firstStr.substring(i + 1);
            secondStr = secondStr.substring(0, j) + secondStr.substring(j + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Mostly your code was valid. You must remove the character from `firstStr` as well as `secondStr` to achieve the wanted result. Also, you can concat strings with just `+`.